# Migrating mongodb cluster - reelections

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

Consider you have to move your mongo cluster from one environment to another, with minimal downtime during the process.

Let's say you have environment 1 (i.e AWS), with the following mongo nodes:

- mongo_aws_1
- mongo_aws_2
- mongo_aws_3

Your application is configured to talk to mongo_aws_1, 2, 3, with hardcoded ip addresses and no DNS names.

What would be the easiest way to move the cluster to another environment (i.e Google Cloud), so that you have

- mongo_gc_1
- mongo_gc_2
- mongo_gc_3
  ?

My migration plan was the following (this ofc assumes connectivity between AWS and GC)

- create new mongo nodes (mongo_gc_1, 2, 3) and add them to existing cluster, with priority = 0 (`rs.add('host': 'mongo_gc_1:27017', 'priority': 0)`). Then wait until the nodes synchronize with replicaset (the entire dataset is less than 15GB, so it's ok to wait)
- redeploy the application so that it talks to both AWS and GC nodes
- change the priority of GC nodes to 1 so that they become fully-fledged members (`rs.reconfig()`)
- remove 'old secondaries' from the cluster
- ask PRIMARY to stepdown (this will force one of GC nodes to become primary)
- remove 'old primary' from the cluster
- redeploy application so it only talks to GC nodes

This should work and the only downtime it introduces is when the old primary steps down.

**However, it assumes that primary does not change during the entire operation.**
On the other hand, according to documentation:

> The rs.reconfig() shell method can force the current primary to step down, which causes an election

also, when you remove a node from the replicaset:

> This function will disconnect the shell briefly and forces a reconnection as the replica set renegotiates which member will be primary. As a result, the shell will display an error even if this command succeeds.

**What should be the proper way of implementing this? Can I somehow avoid the unncessary reelections?**

Answer (score 0):

When you `add` your 3 GC nodes you could also make them `hidden`. Not only can hidden members not become primary they are invisible to client applications.

`rs.add()` provides a wrapper around some of the functionality of the `replSetReconfig` db command and the corresponding shell helper `rs.reconfig`:

[`replSetReconfig`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetReconfig/#dbcmd.replSetReconfig): This command can cause downtime as the set renegotiates primary-status. Therefore, you should attempt to reconfigure only during scheduled maintenance periods.

So by doing it the way you've proposed could cause 3 separate elections:

```
rs.add({host: "mongo_gc_1:27017", priority: 0 })
rs.add({host: "mongo_gc_2:27017", priority: 0 })
rs.add({host: "mongo_gc_3:27017", priority: 0 })
```

You could get that possibility down to only 1 by combining you `priority` and/or `hidden` change in one `reconfig` call:

```
rs.add({host: "mongo_gc_1:27017" })
rs.add({host: "mongo_gc_2:27017" })
rs.add({host: "mongo_gc_3:27017" })

conf = rs.conf() 

conf.members[4].priority = 0
conf.members[5].priority = 0
conf.members[6].priority = 0

conf.members[4].hidden = true
conf.members[5].hidden = true
conf.members[6].hidden = true

rs.reconfig(conf)
```

Comment: A few points here:

- it is possible to add node with priority 0, I've already tested it

- it is probably not possible to lower the priority of existing PRIMARY to 0 (keep getting NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible)

Is it true that rs.reconfig only triggers election only in case the priority of some other node is higher that the priority of current primary?

Comment: @slnowak I've updated my answer regarding the `rs.add`. The documentation is rather vague regarding `rs.reconfig` "can trigger the current primary to step down in some situations" what "some situations' means will probably require testing to find out